# HttpContext.Current is null when WS asmx call class library function

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx, session-state

I have a class library with a function A which uses `HttpContext.Current.Session`
I also have an asmx class with WebMethods which one of them calls the function A in the class library.
When the function A is called by the WS method it fails on the error:

```
Null reference object
```

The `HttpContext.Current` is null! 
I enabled the session in the Web Method by adding the attribute:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
```

but I keep getting the error.
If I call the function A from a simple function in the same project as the WS function it works ok. only from the WS asmx function it fails.
What do I need to do?
It's very important, 
Thanks!!!

Comment: Try passing the `Session` as an argument to your class library function.

Comment: It's not good for me, cause the class library is used by others projects too,

Comment: since you class library is using `HTTPContext`, it is specific to web applications, where each webapp can pass session accordingly.

Comment: How do you call your web method in asmx service? Are you sure that you pass the sessionId cookie with that request? Session cannot be recreated without that information.

Comment: No, I don't send any sessionid to the function. what exactly I have to do? thanks.

Comment: Can you post a code sample of calling your funcion from both working and non-working environments? More details to the context will certainly help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Session["BLABLA"]** instead of `HttpContext.Current.Session`

with

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] attr.
```

My code works with this.

good luck.